# Get PDF download url by API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am currently making a Wordpress plugin as a link between an accounting system. This API manual prescribes that an invoice can be downloaded with:

```
# You can also use wget
curl -X GET https://api.URL.com/invoices/{id}/download \
   -H 'Accept: application / pdf'
```

All other api requests work fine, but here I get the error:

```
{"error": {"code": 422, "key": "params.invalid", "message": "The parameters are invalid (either missing, not of the correct type or incorrect format).", "details" : [{"key": "is_invalid", "param": "id", "message": "is invalid"}]}}
```

I try to make the request with the function below:

```
function download_jortt_invoice() {

    $post_meta_invoice_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_invoice_id', true );
    $api = new API_Client(APPID, APPTOKEN, CallBackUrl);
    
    $auth_token = get_option( 'invoice_read_token');
    $get_download_link = $api->getrequest('invoices/'. $post_meta_invoice_id .'/download', $auth_token);
    $get_download_url = json_decode($get_download_link);

    var_dump($get_download_link);
}
```

When I delete '/download/', I receive the entire invoice list, which is consistent with the manual. However, if I put '/ download' back in the request, this message appears. The manual on how to download a PDF can be found here: https://developer.jortt.nl/#download-invoice-pdf

What am I overlooking or why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is `$order` global var? Have you checked the `$post_meta_invoice_id` value, maybe its `false` because of `$order->id`?

Comment: Yes, `$post_meta_invoice_id` is correct and working. Also `$order->id` is a global var.

Comment: Maybe should check invoice status before request. As manual says `GET /invoices/{id}` returns `invoice_status = 'sent' || 'draft'`. You can request only sent invoice..